# How can I obtain performance benchmarks for using socket.io on a Nodejs app

Tags: sockets, node.js, benchmarking

I have recently been working on a nodejs app which uses open socket connections for all of its communication.  The index is served up through nginx.  I want to benchmark the ability of the server to handle a high amount of load which means I would end up testing my application's ability to manage open sockets, and not its ability to serve up the index file.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [wsbench](http://github.com/pgriess/wsbench) as solution, but you don't necessarily use wsbench for all transports.

For example:

```
node wsbench -c 100 -r 10 ws://example.com:8080/socket.io/websocket
```

Comment: This ended up working for what I needed.  I had some issues with sending messages though.

Comment: care to elaborate on those issues? I think I may be encountering them now.